# (Python) trying to write a Function to reads a dataframe (from excel) and then loop same number of rows into check boxes when the application loads

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, tkinter, global

But I am having a hard time being able to figure out how to .get() from tkinter to call the corresponding value when a particular check box is clicked.

```
class overview:
 def __init__(self,m):
    self.m = m

    m.title("Title")
    m.geometry('800x600')
    m['bg'] = '#2874A6'
    
    self.frame= LabelFrame()
    self.frame.configure(width=210)
    self.frame.grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky = NSEW)
    for x in pind1:
        a = pind1.index(x)
        l = Checkbutton(self.frame, text=names1[a], variable = "N"+str(a), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
        
        l.pack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `variable` option requires an instance of one of tkinter's special variables (`StringVar()`, etc.). You're just passing in a string.

If you want to use a name like `N1`, `N2`, etc, the simplest solution is to use a dictionary to store the variables.

```
self.vars = {}
for x in pind1:
    ...
    var = StringVar()
    self.vars[f"N{a}"] = var
    l = Checkbutton(..., variable = var, ...)
    ...
```

You could also use a list if you don't need to name the variables with a leading "N".

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! This worked for storing the values but I'm still having trouble figuring out how to call or get the true/false from a particular variable name in tkinter?

Comment: @JaredFarley: it's just `self.vars["N1"].get()` or whatever the index is.